# Rolling Reboots of EC2 Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, shell, amazon-ec2, reboot

I was able to sucessfully reboot an group of instances with

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get uptime in seconds 
uptime_seconds=$(awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime | cut -d. -f1)

# Check if uptime is greater than 18 hours (64800 seconds)
if [ "$uptime_seconds" -gt 64800 ]; then echo "Uptime exceeds 18 hours. Initiating reboot."

# Schedule a reboot in 5 minutes   
/sbin/shutdown -r +5 "Scheduled reboot by AWS SSM Maintenance Window"
else echo "Uptime is below 18 hours. No reboot scheduled."
fi

OUTPUT: Uptime exceeds 18 hours. Initiating reboot.
ERROR: Shutdown scheduled for Tue 2024-03-19 13:20:02 UTC, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
```

Was expecting rolling reboots, 2 instances at 13:15 and the other 2 at 13:20.

Instead, what I got was a reboot 13:20 today even with that error message, however it rebooted all 4 instances at that time instead of rolling the reboots 5 minutes after each other. I have the targets set to 2 at a time under concurrency.

Not sure what's going on with my bash script here. Can someone provide me the correct script to space rebooting 5 minutes apart from each instance? or do i need to create a ssm document here with python scripting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.